# SignalR server method not found on IIS

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, iis, signalr

I have the following `SignalR` hub class on the server -

```
    public int Send(string fromID, string fromName, string toID, string message)
    {
        // Implementation
    }


    public void Connected(string username, string userID)
    {                      
        // Implementation
    }

    public List<ChatUser>  GetAllConnectedUsers()
    {
        // Implementation
    }


    public string CheckIfOpenChat(string strByID, string strWithID)
    {
        // Implementation
    }


    public int EndSession(string strByID, string strWithID)
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {     
        // Implementation
    }
```

On the local system, I see all the server methods -

[image]

On IIS though, the server methods are following - 
[image]

Seems like I'm missing server methods on the IIS that are visible on visual studio in development server.

I'm generating the `hub.js` in `global.asax` -

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    }
```

`Chat.js` - I'm initializing the connection to the server.

```
_chat = $.connection.chat;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () { // Implementation }
```

EDIT - Restarted IIS as well. Also my signalR version is **1.1.3**

It seems like the hub.js file generated does not contain the method names specified. I figured it will be the cache, but cleared that as well.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? I believe signal r (HTML5 sockets) isn't supported on all versions of IIS.

Comment: @Liam, Version 8.0.9200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not an error with SignalR. This error was caused because of 'improper publish' by VS 2012. VS 2012 was not publishing the latest DLLs for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

See the following document:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting

Scroll down to this entry:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined" error

This is usually a problem with accessing JQuery- make sure that the path to the JQuery library is correct, and the correct version is referenced.

Comment: Hey sorry I forgot about this question. I've resolved this since then.